# Operating System matching redhat6 could not be found error while installing hdp-3.0

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

While upgrading to hdp-3.0 from hdp-2.6x i am getting following error in ambari.

```
Operating System matching redhat6 could not be found.
```

my linux version is centos6.x and ambari version is 2.6x

how can i fix this issue? whether there is  no support for linux version lower than 7?

[image]

Comment: I believe they dropped support for RHEL 6 with the major version bump

Answer (score 0):

HDP 3.0 no longer supports RHEL/CENTOS 6.

Unfortunately to see the exact supported versions you need to have a support account..

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/support-matrix.html